# Dismiss keyboard when touching anywhere on textView itself

Tags: uitextview

I have a TextView and i want to hide keyboard when touching anywhere on screen including textView itself please give some suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an Objective-C expert, but what worked for me was to drag a `UITapGesterRecognizer` onto my view in Interface Builder and then create the IBOutlet in my .h file and the IBAction in my .m file.  I'm using XCode 5 and iOS 7 - see below:

.h file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITapGestureRecognizer *dismissKeyboard;
```

.m file

```
- (IBAction)dismissKeyboard:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {

    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

The `endEditing`: part of this code dismisses the keyboard.  From Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/endEditing%3a):

> endEditing causes the view (or one of its embedded text fields) to
>   resign the first responder status.

As for tapping "the textView itself" - I don't know how to do that and dismiss the keyboard.  Just out of curiosity, why would you want that functionality?

Comment: You don't need to create the property. Only drag the Tap Gesture Recognizer into your view and link to that action. Very elegant solution, great!

Answer (score 0):

in a UIViewController subclass the basic logic is

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```